# Gradle - Ignore specfic jars from Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar

I am creating a project which creates Jar files out of it and i wanted some of the jars to be excluded from the final jar created from the project.

I am trying as below, even though i have given providedCompile, those jars also included in the final jar.

Tried with providedRuntime, i was getting compile time error. also i want ignore Tomcat related jars, can anyone help me?

```
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"


repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral
}

configurations {
  providedCompile
  compile.extendsFrom providedCompile
}

jar {
  exclude ("*db/**")
}

dependencies {

  compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}") {
    exclude group:"org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
  }

  providedCompile "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0"
  providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${servletApiVersion}"

  // hc-commons jars
  providedCompile "com.test.hc-commons:hc-commons-exception:${hcCommonsVersion}"
  providedCompile "com.test.hc-commons:hc-commons-utils:${hcCommonsVersion}"
  providedCompile "com.test.hc-commons:hc-commons-typeconverters:${hcCommonsVersion}"
  providedCompile "com.test.hc-commons:hc-commons-mailing:${hcCommonsVersion}"

  compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-velocity:${springBootVersion}") {
    exclude group:"org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
  }

}
```

Note: I have tried with provided-base plugin and other suggestions given in the google

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just create a flag and use an if statement to include them for not, or another configuration.

Comment: can you give me some sample on how to use if statement or another configurations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331762/how-to-use-if-else-condition-in-gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve using jar method as below

```
jar {
  from {
        (configurations.runtime - configurations.providedCompile).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : it
        }
    } 
}
```

this jar method create simple jar excluding providedCompile jars but build task still add jar. need to use 'jar' task